# how can I serve static files from a non-default path?

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I'm using Plug.Static to serve static files from my server. The "default" way to do so would be to configure it like so:

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/my_project/assets",
    from: :my_project,
    gzip: true
```

and then I can consume the files in priv/static in the html using for example:

```
<img class='picture' src='<%= static_path(@conn, "/myPicture.png") %>'>
```

So far so good. However, if I want to serve the files from priv/static at a different path, and I use

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/my_project/another_path/assets",
    from: :my_project,
    gzip: true
```

Now I can't access the files using static_path, since it's still resolving to `host.com/assets/my-picture-hash` instead of `host.com/another_path/assets/my-picture-hash`, which is the intended behaviour.

How can I get the actual path of a hashed file when it's not exposed in the default path?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your first example is working? I think that configuration only works when called as `static_path(@conn, "/my_project/assets/myPicture.png)`.

So your second example works when called as `static_path(@conn, "/my_project/another_path/assets/myPicture.png")`

It looks like perhaps you have the `:at` and `:to` options mixed up. This is from the [`Plug.Static` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html):

> `:at` - the request path to reach for static assets. It must be a
>   string.
>
> `:from` - the file system path to read static assets from. It can be
>   either: a string containing a file system path, an atom representing
>   the application name (where assets will be served from `priv/static`),
>   or a tuple containing the application name and the directory to serve
>   assets from (besides `priv/static`).

So to answer the *title* of your question (*how can I serve static files from a non-default path?*); if you want to serve files from a different path instead of the default `priv/static` in your application folder, shouldn't it be:

```
plug Plug.Static, at: "/uploads", from: "/some/other/path"
```

And to show the image located on your disk at `/some/other/path/myPicture.png` (this is an absolute path, not relative to your application):

```
<img class="picture" src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/uploads/myPicture.png") %>">
```

(If this is still not working **and** you have added this as a new `Plug.Static` *after* the default one: place it *before* the default static plug.)

Edit:

And of course, if you want to serve the static assets from the default path (`priv/static` in your app folder) but with a custom url, you can do:

```
plug Plug.Static, at: "/some/path", from: :my_project
```

and serve them as:

```
<img class="picture" src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/some/path/myPicture.png") %>">
```